# Split & extract part of string (between a "." and digit) in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a character variable (`companies`) with observations that look like this:

1. "612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33"
2. "77. Wickes 4.61"
3. "265. Wang Labs 8.75"
4. "9. CrossLand Savings 6.32"
5. "228. JPS Textile Group 2.00"

I'm trying to split these strings into 3 parts:

1. all the digits before the first `"."` ,
2. everything between the first `"."` and the next number
   (consistently formatted `#.##`), and
3. that last number itself
   (format `#.##`).

Using the first obs as an example, I'd like: "612", "Grt. Am. Mgt & Inv", "5.01"

I've tried defining the pattern in `rebus` and using `str_match`, but the code below only works on cases like obs #2 and #3. It doesn't reflect all the variation in the middle part of the string to capture the other obs.

```
pattern2 <- capture(one_or_more(DGT)) %R% DOT %R% SPC %R% 
            capture(or(one_or_more(WRD), one_or_more(WRD) %R% SPC 
            %R% one_or_more(WRD))) %R% SPC %R% capture(DGT %R% DOT 
            %R% one_or_more(DGT))

str_match(companies, pattern = pattern2)
```

Is there a better way to split the strings into these 3 parts?

I'm not familiar with `regex`, but I've seen that suggested here a lot (I'm brand new to R and Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to debug the regex you wrote.

```
> as.regex(pattern2)
<regex> ([\d]+)\.\s((?:[\w]+|[\w]+\s[\w]+))\s(\d\.[\d]+)
```

[Plug it in](https://regex101.com/r/ylIYVw/1) at regex101, and you see your strings do not always match. The explanation on the right tells you that you only allow 1 or 2 space separated words between the dot and number. Also, `WRD` (`[\w]+` pattern) does not match dots and any other chars that are not letters, digits or `_`. Now, you know you need to match your string with

```
^(\d+)\.(.*?)\s*(\d\.\d{2})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tdv3Yq/2). Translating into Rebus:

```
pattern2 <- START %R%            # ^ - start of string
 capture(one_or_more(DGT)) %R%   # (\d+) - Group 1: one or more digits
 DOT %R%                         # \. - a dot
 "(.*?)" %R%                     # (.*?) - Group 2: any 0+ chars as few as possible
 zero_or_more(SPC) %R%           # \s* - 0+ whitespaces 
 capture(DGT %R% DOT %R% repeated(DGT, 2)) %R% # (\d\.\d{2}) - Group 3: #.## number
END                              # $ - end of string
```

Checking:

```
> pattern2
<regex> ^([\d]+)\.(.*?)[\s]*(\d\.[\d]{2})$

> companies <- c("612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33","77. Wickes 4.61","265. Wang Labs 8.75","9. CrossLand Savings 6.32","228. JPS Textile Group 2.00")
> str_match(companies, pattern = pattern2)
     [,1]                             [,2]  [,3]                    [,4]  
[1,] "612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33" "612" " Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv." "7.33"
[2,] "77. Wickes 4.61"                "77"  " Wickes"               "4.61"
[3,] "265. Wang Labs 8.75"            "265" " Wang Labs"            "8.75"
[4,] "9. CrossLand Savings 6.32"      "9"   " CrossLand Savings"    "6.32"
[5,] "228. JPS Textile Group 2.00"    "228" " JPS Textile Group"    "2.00"
```

**WARNING**: the `capture(lazy(zero_or_more(ANY_CHAR)))` returns `([.]*?)` pattern that matches 0 or more dots as few as possible instead of matching any 0+ chars, because `rebus` has a bug: it wraps all the `repeated` (`one_or_more` or `zero_or_more`) chars with `[` and `]`, a character class. That is why `(.*?)` is added "manually".

This can be resolved, or worked around, using a common construct like `[\w\W]` / `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]`:

```
pattern2 <- START %R%                          # ^ - start of string
 capture(one_or_more(DGT)) %R%                 # (\d+) - Group 1: one or more digits
 DOT %R%                                       # \. - a dot
 capture(                                      # Group 2 start:
  lazy(zero_or_more(char_class(WRD, NOT_WRD))) #  - [\w\W] - any 0+ chars as few as possible
 ) %R%                                         # End of Group 2
 zero_or_more(SPC) %R%                         # \s* - 0+ whitespaces 
 capture(DGT %R% DOT %R% repeated(DGT, 2)) %R% # (\d\.\d{2}) - Group 3: #.## number
END
```

Check:

```
> as.regex(pattern2)
<regex> ^([\d]+)\.([\w\W]*?)[\s]*(\d\.[\d]{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tdv3Yq/3).

Comment: Thanks for this super detailed explanation! It worked well, and I learned a lot from your comments.

Answer (score 3):

You can delimit your string using regex and then split that strings for getting your results:

```
delimitedString = gsub( "^([0-9]+). (.*) ([0-9.]+)$", "\\1,\\2,\\3", companies  )

do.call( 'rbind', strsplit(split = ",", x = delimitedString) )
#      [,1]  [,2]                   [,3]  
#[1,] "612" "Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv." "7.33"
#[2,] "77"  "Wickes"               "4.61"
#[3,] "265" "Wang Labs"            "8.75"
#[4,] "9"   "CrossLand Savings"    "6.32"
#[5,] "228" "JPS Textile Group"    "2.00"
```

**Regex explanation**:

- `^[0-9]+` : any pattern composed by numbers from 0 to 9 at the beginning (i.e. `^`) of your string
- `.*` : greedy match, basically anything surrounded by two spaces on the above case
- `[0-9.]+$`: again numbers + a point and at the ending (i.e. `$`) of your string

Parenthesis are used to indicate that I want to catch those part of *string* which are fitted by regex. Upon caught them, those substring are collapsed and delimited by commas. Finally, we can split the whole string with `strsplit` function and bind rows with `do.call` function

Comment: Thanks, Ulises! This worked too. The explanation is really helpful

Comment: I am glad to know it helps out, @Chan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the text, you can match the information using a grouping regex and extract the information from three groups you want. Try using this regex,

```
(.+?)\.\s+(.+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)
```

Which will capture your information in group1, group2 and group3.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTmP7e/1)**

Here, group1 captures your first number before company information, and group2 captures the company information and group3 captures the last number of form `#.##`

Check this r code,

```
companies = c("612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33")
result <- str_match(companies, pattern = "(.+?)\\.\\s+(.+)\\s+(\\d+\\.\\d+)")
result[,2]
result[,3]
result[,4]
```

Prints,

```
[1] "612"
[1] "Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv."
[1] "7.33"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

`^(.*?)\.(.*?)(?=\d)(.*)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qyqOPs/1)

The three capturing groups contain the desired information: the first group captures everything until it finds the first `'.'`, the second group captures everything until it finds a digit (this is done via *positive lookahead*, which ensures that the digit isn't consumed since we need to capture it in the next group), and the third group captures everything till the end.

Comment: Thanks! The demo helped clarify a lot

Answer (score 1):

You might use 3 capturing groups:

```
([^.]+)\.\s+(\D+)\s+(\d\.\d{2})
```

For example

```
companies=c("612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33")
pattern="([^.]+)\\.\\s+(\\D+)\\s+(\\d\\.\\d{2})"
str_match(companies, pattern)
```

Result

```
     [,1]                             [,2]  [,3]                   [,4]  
[1,] "612. Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv. 7.33" "612" "Grt. Am. Mgt. & Inv." "7.33"
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/82rDDX/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/Bys6H2)

**Explanation**

- `([^.]+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ times not a dot (To not match a newline as well, use `[^.\r\n]` )
- `\.\s+` Match a dot and 1+ times a whitespace character
- `(\D+)` Capture in group 2 matching 1+ times not a digit
- `\s+` Match 1+ times a whitespace character
- `(\d\.\d{2})` Capture in group 3 a digit, dot and 2 digits (format #.##)